# Dynamically instantiating object Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, object, dynamic, instantiation

In Java we can instantiate an object (knowing only the parameters types) dynamically like this:

```
Class<?> msgClass = Class.forName(className);
constructor = msgClass.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, String.class);    
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) constructor.newInstance(myString, myString2, myString3);    

    public class MyClass {        
        public MyClass(String s, String s2, String s2){}
    }
```

Is there a way to do the same in objective-c, knowing only the parameters types to be passed in to the objective-c class constructor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, depending on what you're really doing. ObjC doesn't have language-level "constructors" in the same way-- there are `init` methods which usually called alongside the `alloc` instantiation method, but note that `init` is there by framework convention and not by spec, so the runtime doesn't "know" what "constructor" you'd want to call.

You can instantiate an object (the equivalent of allocating it) like this:

```
id myObj = class_createInstance(NSClassFromString(@"MyClass"));
```

although you might as well do it more directly:

```
id myObj = [NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc];
```

But then you'd still need to call whatever `init` method you want on it. If you don't want to do this directly, you need to know the selector for the method so you can send the object the correct message. The selector is a static representation of the message signature. You could invoke that method through the runtime API like this:

```
myObj = objc_msgSend(myObj, @selector(initWithStr1:str2:str3), myString1, myString2, myString3);
// Check myObj for nil which means a failed init.
```

---

ObjC runtime reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: so if i don't know the constructor/method/selector name of the class then i really can't call it even though I know the parameters. Is there some sort of look up to find the selector based on the parameters the can take.

Comment: If you know the parameters, why don't you know the selector? Message sending is dynamic in Obj-C, and the selector is *the thing* that identifies method you're calling. (It's not like Java where you could say "get me the c'tor that takes three params"-- there might be multiple things that start with "init..." that look like that, and you'd want to know which you were calling.) Look at the runtime docs linked above. You can iterate through methods using the `class_copyMethodList` function, and inspect their names and selectors and arguments, etc.

Comment: I agree with you in a case that i should know the selector name, however in a case where i designed my class to have multiple selector (init) with the same name but different parameters types are being passed. How can i distinguish the difference between them? I hope i am clear and Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't declare a class that way; the compiler won't let you. A method cannot have the same name as another method but with different argument types. That's why ObjC init methods have names like `-initWithName:title:subtitle` and `-initWithDate:attributes:flags`. They both take 3 arguments, but have different names, and thus different selectors. You should ask a new question here that details exactly what you're trying to accomplish-- you might get some idiomatic ObjC design help.